Installing Glad Package with Conan on No Internet Machine
I'm working on a machine where terminals/scripts are not allowed to access the internet. I'm trying to get the Glad package installed using Conan and have Conan pick up the local tar.gz file. This works for loading and beginning to build the package, but as it proceeds with the build, glad.opener tries download gl.xml off the internet, and so the build fails. I have this file locally downloaded as well, but I can't seem to figure out how to pick up this file during the build process. Here is the error:
1>Checking Build System
  Generating GLAD
  [06/04/2024 10:30:27][INFO    ][glad          ]: using local specification: 'gl.xml'
  [06/04/2024 10:30:27][INFO    ][glad          ]: generating 'gl' bindings: {'gl': Version(major=3, minor=3)}
  [06/04/2024 10:30:27][INFO    ][glad.opener   ]: saving: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/EGL-Registry/main/api/KHR/khrplatform.h' to 'C:\Users\<username>\.conan\data\glad\0.1.36\build\64ea2c1e524a3ebc640d603498f0453dc472051d\b
  uild\include\KHR\khrplatform.h'

...

urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>

Here is what my source() function looks like currently (I can show more of the recipe if needed):
def source(self):
        get(self, "file:///E:/ConanLibrariesOrInstallers/glad/glad-0.1.36.tar.gz", strip_root=True)
        local_file_path = "E:/ConanLibrariesOrInstallers/glad/xml"
        copy(self,src=local_file_path, pattern="*" ,dst="." )

I've tried to download the file locally and amend the source() function in the Conan recipe to copy this file over, trying to sidestep the download, but that doesn't work. I've also tried setting the "no_loader" option to true as well, trying to never start looking for that file in the first place, and that also didn't work.

This looks like something very specific to the recipe and specifically to the Glad build system that decides to download a file from the internet while building, which is not great. This might require some more advanced patching to the Glad recipe beyond this, so submitting tickets to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues would be recommended.
